# vs.net go to parent class (shortcut)

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there an easy way open the parent class code file in visual studio.

I know i can use the inherits and go to defintion to go to the base class in C#. But in vb.net the inherits is hidden in designer code for a lot of files I am working on and I'm looking for a simple way to open the parent class.

Bonus points for whoever gives me a go to parent class function defintion over overloaded functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no such keyboard short cut, or underlying command that I know of, which will take you to the parent of the current class.

The only keyboard style shortcut I can think of for this scenario is the following

- Type "MyBase"
- Hit the Goto Definition keyboard shortcut (can't remember it off the top of my head)

Not exactly what you're looking for since it changes the current file but it's the closest I can think of.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by smink, the only way I know of to currently perform this action is via the *Resharper* Visual Studio Extension.

If you already have Resharper, the hotkey you are looking for is:

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd>

You can change it by modifying the following in the Visual Studio Keyboard shortcuts menu:

> ReSharper.ReSharper_GotoBase

While purchasing this extension solely for this problem is likely not a desirable solution, those who already own it will hopefully find this helpful.

Comment: What about Go to base for the currently opened class? Where the cursor is.

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box I think not. But if you have some money to spare, **read well spent**, install [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/). It will have visual aids to the code editor that will allow you to perform that operation.

Comment: This works really good, but Resharper is a bit heavy/expensive for just one function.